# Driver certification on Windows

Tags: windows, drivers

I'm developing a device driver for use on Windows. Does the driver have to be certified by Microsoft to install? Are there any pitfalls of which I should be aware?

This is for use on Windows XP, Windows Vista, and Windows 7.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, your driver does not have to be certified to install.  However, if you are using 64-bit windows, it will need to be [signed](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/driver/install/drvsign/default.mspx).

Answer (score 2):

You can bypass the signing requirement for development purposes as documented in *[Installing an Unsigned Driver during Development and Test](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff547565%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)* (MSDN).